# Elements not lining up until after turning CSS rule off and on again

Tags: html, css

I have a layout built using CSS display:table (inline, row, cell, etc). I'm doing local development on it with apache, and when I refresh the page, two of the div containers are incorrectly lined up. However, if I uncheck and re-check display:table-row, they correct themselves, and the page displays correctly.

http://jsfiddle.net/fNNKT/

You can see the HTML and CSS at the jsFiddle above. It's actually not working there either, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, and can use help with that.

```
                <div class="cabinet-container">
                <div class="mode-bar">
                    <div class="mode-bar-left">
                        <div class="mode-bar-item">logo</div>
                        <div class="mode-bar-item active">Dispense</div>
                        <div class="mode-bar-item">Inventory</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mode-bar-right schedule">
                        <div class="mode-bar-item">Sign-Out</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div class="table"></div>
                    <div class="left-container"></div>
                    <div class="center-container">
                        <div class="search-container">
                            <div class="table-cell">
                                <div class="search-field"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-button-center-container">
                            <div class="table-cell">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list">
                            <div class="table-cell">
                                <div class="list-item-center-container"></div>
                                <div class="list-item-center-container"></div>
                                <div class="list-item-center-container-partial"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-button-center-container-down-active">
                            <div class="table-cell"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="button-group table-border-5">
                            <div class="button-secondary">Dispense Non-Drug</div>
                            <div class="button-secondary">Sort By: Last Name</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="button-group-right table-border-5">
                            <div class="button-primary">New Clinical Order</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your question related to `.mode-bar-left` and `.mode-bar-right` wrapping onto two lines? If so, the problem relates to whitespace. Think of two images displayed inline, side by side. If there's whitespace between the tags in the code, there will be whitespace displayed in the browser.

**Solution #1:**
Take your logic one level higher up in the DOM. Change the `display` value for both mode-bar elements to `table-cell` (instead of the current `inline-table`). Then change the `.mode-bar-item` elements to `display: inline-block` (instead of `table-cell`).

**Solution #2:**
A faster, less elegant solution is to add `float: left` to `.mode-bar-left`.

On the topic of elegance, I *strongly* recommend that you consider some more semantically meaningful tags than just `div`. For example, `.mode-bar-left` is clearly a list (`ul` perhaps?) and the `.mode-bar-item` elements are clearly list items (`li`).

Comment: Not doing float, the reason I'm shifting to css:table layout is b/c of the horror of the current implementation's float/clear/absolutes.

Comment: As for the issue, If you expand the jsFiddle result width the mode-bar stuff lines up fine (although you are correct that I may be better served with LI). The issue is with the 'left container' and center container'. Specifically, the center container should be top-aligned with the left container but currently it isn't.

Comment: Ah--so in responding to you I solved it--the 'center container' needed a vertical-align: top applied to it. I feel a little dumb now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any javascript/jQuery? On a recent project of my own, I was having a similar issue and all I had to do was move my custom lightbox script from the  to right before the  tag, and it seemed to fix the issue. Sometimes javascript can be wonky like that. I don't understand why, but that's the way it is.

Comment: I am, but not in the JS fiddle example, which is still off-aligned...I'll have to play around with turning them off and seeing if it works (though, again, with it not working on jsFiddle it lends me to believe that's not the issue).